# Couldn't solve hostname for single host from my PC - ping not working

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I can't reach another machine from my PC anymore, while other PCs can; I can't understand the problem, something got broken on my PC about DNS or something else.

Some more details:

- The target host is a Win Home notebook, not in domain
- other PCs can ping the target and browse its shared folders
- from my PC I can't neither ping it using hostname (could not find host  Please check the name) nor using the IP (host is unreachable)
- tracert gives a "Unable to resolve target system name" error
- I can reach (ping/browse/connect) to all other PC in the LAN

I tried:

```
ipconfig /flush dns
ipconfig /register dns
```

This did not resolve the issue so far. Any other suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: What makes you assume it's a DNS issue if you can't reach the host by its IP address either (which doesn't use DNS)?

Comment: OK, it's not a DNS problem, it was just the first thought. I would like to know what the problem is in fact.

Comment: have you verified that both hosts involved have a unique, valid IP address for the LAN? is the target system connected to the same network?

Comment: Yes, IPs are valid, unique, on the same LAN. As I wrote the problem seems to be only on my PC side, others PC can reach the target PC. And I can reach other PCs.